# C# WriteDocType generates an incorrect PList doctype

Tags: c#, plist, doctype, xmltextwriter

Consider the following C# code:

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(pathFichier, null);
writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteDocType("plist", "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN", "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd", null);
writer.WriteStartElement("plist");
writer.WriteAttributeString("version", "1.0");
writer.WriteFullEndElement(); // plist
writer.Close();
```

A PList doctype is usually:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
```

The above code adds an empty subset at the end of the doctype string:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"[]>
```

The "[]" at the end screws with iOs's parsing.

How can I get rid of it using XmlTextWriter ?

Should I just reopened the file and delete the "[]" ?

Comment: There's an easier workaround, as seen in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358061/c-sharp-linq-to-xml-remove-characters-from-the-dtd-header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can derive a class for XmlTextWriter and [override the WriteDocType method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417683/add-html-5-doctype-to-xdocument-net).

It'd look something like this:

```
public override void WriteDocType(string name, string pubid, string sysid, string subset)
{
    this.wrappedWriter.WriteRaw("-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN", "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd");
}
```

EDIT by the guy who asked the question. Here's the code I wrote to make it work.

The WriteDocType override:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace your.namespace {
    public class PListWriter : System.Xml.XmlTextWriter  {

        public PListWriter(string filename, System.Text.Encoding encoding) : base(filename, encoding) { }

        public override void WriteDocType(string name = "", string pubid = "", string sysid = "", string subset = "") {
            this.WriteRaw("<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">");
        }
    }
}
```

Its usage in the wild:

```
PListWriter writer = new PListWriter(pathFichier, null);    
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteDocType();
writer.WriteStartElement("plist");
writer.WriteAttributeString("version", "1.0");
writer.WriteFullEndElement(); // plist
writer.Close();
```